# Rails 3.1 Bizarre ActiveRecord Behavior in Create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, update-attributes

Using Rails 3.1.0

```
def create
@practice = Practice.new(params[:practice])

respond_to do |format|
  if (current_user.practices << @practice rescue false)

    pmf = current_user.practices_users.inspect # if this line is removed the following update_attributes method breaks!

    current_user.practices_users.last.update_attributes(:admin_flg => true, :first_name => params[:first_name], :last_name => params[:last_name])
    format.html { redirect_to home_dashboard_path, notice: 'Practice was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @practice, status: :created, location: @practice }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @practice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

When the 'pmf = ...'  line is not present, I get this line

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass
```

When the 'pmf = ...' line is present, the create action works normally.  What is going on?

Comment: what is the size of `current_user.practices_users` when you do not have the `pmf = ` line? It might be the transaction has not yet been comitted

Comment: When you say that the "method breaks", what do you mean? What's the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact answer but I can help you debug...

When you do

```
pmf = current_user.practices_users.inspect
```

then Rails is loading the whole set of `practices_users` (for current_user) from the database and when you call `last` a little bit later, it is calling the method `last` on an object of type `Array`.

When you do

```
current_user.practices_users.last
```

without having made your pmf call, the whole set of `practices_users` has not been loaded from the database into an array, and Rails is not going to load the whole set because all you want is the last one.  It would be a waste to load an array of items when all it needs to load is the last one.  So it will generate SQL that only loads a single row from the database.

In this sort of situation, you need to look at your console or development log to see exactly what SQL Rails is generating and why that SQL isn't returning any value.  Then it will become clear what's going on.

Comment: Thank you.  You got me started, it will be a little bit before I have time to chase down the issue fully.